# android layout auto adjust to different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-layout-weight

I have below xml nested with Linear Layout and assigned weightSum but with different screen sizes few editText are overlapping eachother or are moving out of the screen. I tried changing value for weightSum and adding layout_weight but my xml is not compatible to different screen sizes. How can I make them compatible for all screen sizes? Any suggestions?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#5BBEE7ED"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtPond"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Pond / Tank Size"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtDensity"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtPond"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Stocking Density (m2)"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtShrimp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtDensity"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Number of Shrimp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtBodyWt"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtShrimp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Average Body Weight"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtOxy"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="395dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtBodyWt"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Oxygen"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtTemp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="395dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtOxy"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Temperature"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtPh"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="395dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtTemp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Ph"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Submit" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the libraries https://github.com/intuit/ssp https://github.com/intuit/sdp

add this in the dependencies
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'

Comment: I added but still the same

Comment: Have you changed dp to android:layout_marginRight="15dp" to android:layout_marginRight="@dimen_15sdp"

Comment: @ Khar Varsha - yes I replaced all "dp" to "@dimen_15sdp" but these android:id="@+id/edtOxy", android:id="@+id/edtTemp" and android:id="@+id/edtPh" are not resizing dynamically to different screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#5BBEE7ED"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtPond"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Pond / Tank Size"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtDensity"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtPond"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Stocking Density (m2)"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtShrimp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtDensity"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Number of Shrimp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtBodyWt"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtShrimp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Average Body Weight"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtOxy"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtBodyWt"
                android:hint="Oxygen"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/edtTemp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtOxy"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Temperature"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
           android:id="@+id/edtPh"
           style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:padding="10dp"
           app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="13dp"
           app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="13dp"
           app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="13dp"
           app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="13dp"
           app:endIconMode="clear_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edtTemp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:hint="Ph"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!--Button-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Submit" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Try to use sdp/ssp library instead of dp

Comment: Use Constraint layout instead of Relative/ Linear Layout. Then it will same in all the screen resolutions.